# Eclipse Plugin change Language programmatically

Tags: eclipse, locale, rcp, properties-file

I am trying to change the language of my RCP plugin programmatically. I had no luck so far. The Approach below is not working for me. After restart the language does not change. I populate a `Menu` dynamically with listet Translation files in a specific folder. The method `LanguageSelectedListener.widgetSelected` when a `MenuItem` is selected. Tried this with an exported product and also running from eclipse.

```java
private void setMenuLanguages(Menu menu){

    File dir = new File(this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getFile() + language_directory);
    String[] dirList = dir.list();

    String currentLocale = System.getProperty("user.language");
    Locale current = new Locale(currentLocale, "", "");
    Locale[] locales = new Locale[dirList.length];
    LanguageSelectedListener listener = new LanguageSelectedListener();

    for(int i=0; i<dirList.length; i++){
        String file = dirList[i].split(".properties")[0];
        String locShort;

        if(file.equals("messages"))locShort = "en"; //default english
        else    locShort = file.split("_")[1];
        locales[i] = new Locale(locShort);

        MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.RADIO, i);
        menuItem.setText(locales[i].getDisplayName());
        menuItem.setData("locale", locales[i]);
        menuItem.addSelectionListener(listener);
        if(locales[i].getLanguage().equals(current.getLanguage()))
                menuItem.setSelection(true);
    }

    return;
}

private class LanguageSelectedListener extends SelectionAdapter{

    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        MenuItem item = (MenuItem) e.widget;
        if(!item.getSelection() || !MessageDialog.openQuestion(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell(), "Info", "Programm wird neu gestartet. Möchten Sie fortfahren?")){
            item.setSelection(false);
            return;
        }

        Locale locale = (Locale) item.getData("locale");

         StringBuffer arguments = new StringBuffer();
         arguments.append("${eclipse.vm}\n"); //$NON-NLS-1$
         arguments.append("-nl\n").append(locale.getLanguage()).append("\n"); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$ //$NON-NLS-3$


         System.setProperty("eclipse.exitcode", Integer.toString(IApplication.EXIT_RELAUNCH)); //$NON-NLS-1$
         System.getProperties().setProperty(IApplicationContext.EXIT_DATA_PROPERTY, arguments.toString());
         PlatformUI.getWorkbench().restart();
    }
}
```

so I implemented the hacky solution by manipulating the ini file of the product (not the config.ini file). Works pretty well for me.

```java
 String installLoc = Platform.getInstallLocation().getURL().getPath();
 String oldIniLocation = installLoc + "decoder.ini";
        String content = null;
        File oldIni = null;

        try {
            oldIni = new File(oldIniLocation);
            content = FileUtils.readFileToString(oldIni, "UTF-8");

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("reading from file failed!", e1);
        }

        Locale locale = (Locale) item.getData("locale");

        if(content.contains("-nl")){
            content = content.replaceFirst("-nl\r\n..", "-nl\r\n" + locale.getLanguage());
        }
        else{
            StringBuilder newContent = new StringBuilder("-nl\r\n" + locale.getLanguage() +"\r\n");
            content = newContent.append(content).toString();
        }

        File newIni = new File(installLoc + "rename.ini");
        try {
            FileUtils.writeStringToFile(newIni, content, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("writing to file failed!", e1);
        }

        oldIni.delete();
        //renaming newIni by moving it
        oldIni = new File(installLoc + "decoder.ini");
        try {
            FileUtils.moveFile(newIni, oldIni);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("renaming/moving file failed!", e1);
        }

        System.setProperty("eclipse.exitcode", Integer.toString(IApplication.EXIT_RESTART)); //$NON-NLS-1$
        PlatformUI.getWorkbench().restart();
```

Comment: Best question where gives in world